# python parse xml string

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

I'm trying to parse data from a website and cannot print the data.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from urllib import urlopen

link = urlopen('http://weather.aero/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&stationString=KSFO&hoursBeforeNow=1')

tree = ET.parse(link)
root = tree.getroot()

data = root.findall('data/metar')
for metar in data:
    print metar.find('temp_c').text
```

Comment: How would I go about parsing the sky condition? 1) The string is conditional based on the weather so it/s always changing. 2) It's not like temp_c and temp_f, all the sky conditions are in one field name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is case sensitive:

```
data = root.findall('data/METAR')
```

Comment: @Savvis If this answers your question, you should mark it as the accepted answer (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)